# How to connect Node-RED flow to the IoT Platform in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

How to connect Node-RED flow to the IoT Platform in IBM Cloud now, since the ibmiot nodes from Node-RED are gone? Almost all Node-RED based IoT tutorials for IBM Cloud referred to IoT Platform starter and those nodes. When running Node-Red in the IBM Cloud, there used to be "IBM IoT in" and "IBM IoT out" nodes which allowed to easily connect to the IBM Watson IoT platform. But now, they are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IoT Platform Starter has been removed from IBM Cloud for some time now. Yet it is fairly easy to add the IoT Platform service to the “vanilla” Node-Red Starter app in IBM Cloud. As soon as it is provisioned you can install the “IBMIoT” *input* and *output* nodes using the manage palette menu option in Node-RED. Follow this blog post for more details: https://medium.com/@blumareks/iot-adventure-with-a-sensor-for-a-pet-hamster-part-2-ed56b7e3d21e?source=friends_link&sk=8b9bc03fd0521ae52413476f73c6d987